# Vertical- and right-align an unknown-height div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

### Issue

I need to vertically center the order_form div (light gray) and keep it on the very right side of each of the product boxes on our website.  The div's height is non-fixed, and can occasionally fill most of its allowed vertical space (which is 160px because of the product image).  The picture div vertical-aligns perfectly.  I made an example out of one product box and simplified it as much as possible while leaving its html intact.

Here's a [jsfiddle displaying the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/g5Edu/) (sorry for the lack of images!)

I realize there are a lot of posts on this topic; I've read many of them.  I've tried everything I could think of, and everything I have found in all the articles, solved questions, even every little clue I've found over the past three+ hours.  Nothing has worked.

I'm completely lost on how to solve this, and I'm sorely tempted to change the picture and order_form divs to a table just for the sake of aligning  ._.

Help?

### Several things I've tried:

- `display: table-cell; vertical-align:middle;` on the order_form div, and adding `display:table` to its parent.
- The above with `display:table` on an added wrapper div instead.
- adding a wrapper div and using margin + negative margin.
- `display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;` and adding a wrapper div with `left:160px; display:table`.  The wrapper div's width is never correct, breaking the order_form.
- `vertical-align:middle` on the order_form and having `height` equal to `line-height` on its container
- several other approaches i do not remember
- saying please.

### Asides

I need this to be functional on somewhat older browsers (ex: IE8), without using any javascript.

Background info: I've recently started working on our site and, among other things, I've since converted all the product boxes from tables to divs and cleaned up the css a bit.  The problem is the tables, being tables, handled the aligning really well...

Also: The next step is to convert the buttons from images to prettyful css links so they scale nicely along with the text (and ditch the table there, too).  Don't dock me points for what I haven't touched yet!

Comment: After some frustrated edits and adding additional wrappers, I finally got it working!  Aiiiii...
For anyone else fighting with this same issue, here's my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/g5Edu/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question rightly, one option would be to set `div.order_form` to `display: table; height: 160px;` and then create a div inside that (wrapping around all its content) and give that inner div `display: table-cell`. That still requires the use of the absolute positioning, which isn't ideal, but it does work.

Comment: I tried this on the jsfiddle (and noticed i missed combining two of the order_form sass blocks..).  It aligns properly, except.. the content div's height changes to fit the container's 160px height.  Sort of the right direction, but still doesn't quite work :(

Comment: Done.  I've included your suggestion by adding div.order_form_content and moving the appropriate styles.  As you can see, its height is getting stretched. any clue how to fix this?
link: http://jsfiddle.net/g5Edu/1/
(I also merged the two style blocks, though that's largely irrelevant.)

Comment: The solution was to add a third div acting as the contents of the display:table-cell div.  Thanks for leading me to the solution!

Answer (score 0):

If you want this on old browsers too..

wanna use some jquery scripts?

The height will auto adjust depending on your order_form height.

See DEMO on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kdNnw/

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // get dynamic height of order_form and calsulate margin-top css
    var ver_top = ( 160 - $('.order_form').height()) / 2;
    $('.order_form').css( "margin-top", ver_top+'px' );
});
```

Comment: I suppose I should have specified: my boss wants absolutely no javascript on our site, only pure html and css.  The things I could do with a little jquery! It's a pity.